# How to match the last number in a row with uipath matches activity?

Tags: regex, uipath

I would like to match the last value from each row from a PDF file with matches activity - in a loop.

https://regex101.com/r/fudpxa/1

(?<=\n2019\s.*)([0-9.,-]+$)

The pattern is "quit simple", but if i apply this pattern in UiPath (Matches activity), it doesn't work.

Comment: It [works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d2019.*%29%28%5b0-9.%2c-%5d%2b%24%29&i=2019+00000+11111+RegExpTest+5015%2c15+5015%2c51) testing it for a .NET regex. Try it without the lookbehind matching 2019  with a space after 2019 and a space before the capturing group `^.*2019 .* ([0-9.,-]+)$`

Comment: Thanks - but the pattern works only in that case if there are no more lines. https://imgur.com/NDozvs5, https://imgur.com/NHoTONT

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/pdQbJJ/1

Comment: Yes, i have tested it a few times with different patterns, i don't understand why is it impossible to use this in uipath...? :/ "....Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: to be honest it would be much easier just to match the last values/number from the row on this example.. https://regex101.com/r/SnMINb/4

Comment: If you want to capture the last values and the string should start with 4 digits you might use https://regex101.com/r/B0jHKi/1 or a bit more specific https://regex101.com/r/B0jHKi/2

Comment: thanks for the GREAT examples, unfortunately non of them work in UiPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resolved after upgrading UiPath Studio from 2018.4.4 to 2019.7

Comment: Hi Manigandan, Thanks for your comment. I've tried almost everything to get the value from the relevant raw (https://imgur.com/rIZZe0d) - 2015 is just an example, i will use a variable to identify the row. Once I use this pattern I get an error...and the Castiterator will be empty/null. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @neptun, I'm able to see the value returned with the same expression you are using. Please check here https://imgur.com/a/HLxtdx9 
BTW, I am using 2019.7 version.

Comment: wow, looks great!!! i'm using 2018.4.4. May I kindly ask you to share the workflow somehow?

Comment: This upload does not exist, can you look into this?

Comment: Sorry that link didn't work for some reason. I have uploaded to this new location. You may have to make changes to project.json file to make it compatible  with your version of UiPath Studio. 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4c659914abfee96874eb186e51f6570720190805093615/a69768c5892ba8c59e86f9c050b49f4920190805093615/ebe912

Comment: Thanks a lot, Manigandan! I don't have any problem since I installed the same version... there was no problem with the original pattern!

Comment: That's good to know. I've updated the answer in case someone faces similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Read FULL PDF** instead of READ PDF Text activity - makes more sense.